# SPA Knockout JS Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I developed MVC 4 Single Page Application using ADO.Net as a data source.  Trying to filter the view by ID, tried session variables without any luck.  Here is the view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/BloodPressuresViewModel.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        upshot.metadata(@(Html.Metadata<KOTest2.Controllers.DALController>()));

        var viewModel = new MyApp.BloodPressuresViewModel({
            serviceUrl: "@Url.Content("~/api/DAL")"
        });
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

and hee is the calss code in the Javascript file:

```
.....
  var entityType = "BloodPressure:#KOTest2.Models";
    MyApp.BloodPressure = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        // Underlying data
        self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
        self.PHN = ko.observable(data.PHN);
        self.Day = ko.observable(data.Day);
        self.Systolic = ko.observable(data.Systolic);
        self.Diastolic = ko.observable(data.Diastolic);
        self.HeartRate = ko.observable(data.HeartRate);
        upshot.addEntityProperties(self, entityType);
    }
.....
```

I think the best solution is to pass the ID using ViewBag to the view from the controller.  Any idea how I can do that!!

Since I am not experienced programmer, will it be possible to filter (foreach)

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: bloodPressures">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. What are you trying to filter? It looks like you already have the ID on the page.

Comment: The ID is in the class, I need to filter the database using the ID when the user login.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand how you access the database (on the server, right?) to do the filtering, but you could do something like this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr>
        <td>id: <span data-bind="text: ID"></span></td>
        <td>PHN: <span data-bind="text: PHN"></span></td>
        ....
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in your javascript

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.loggedIn = ko.observable(false);
    this.rows = ko.observableArray([]);

    // return an array of objects to display to the user
    function getDataFromServer() {

         return ...;
    }

    ko.computed(function() {
        if (this.loggedIn())
            this.rows(getDataFromServer());
    },this);

    ...
}
```

However you do your authentication, after it succeeds, execute `this.loggedIn(true)` which will cause the computed function to trigger the pull from the server and the setting of the `this.rows()`; this in turn will update the display.